# Insert new <td> into a table that fills using data-url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generate my table using bootstrap and

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-url="url.php?...">
```

At the end of each row I want to have a button.

I tried this in my js file but don't know if I'm even close

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function buttons() {
        $("#table tr").append(

            "<td>Button1</td>" +
            "<td>Button2</td>"

        );
    }
});
```

Comment: when do you call the function `buttons()`

Comment: I want it to be called as soon as the document has loaded. I thought that functions inside the .ready were run as soon as the document had finished loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will only declare a function doesnot execute it.

```
function buttons() {
        ...
 }
```

You need to call it using `buttons()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function buttons() {
        $("#table tr").append("<td>Button1</td>" +"<td>Button2</td>");
    }
    buttons();
});
```

Or you could remove the wrapper `buttons()` function just use it directly inside `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#table tr").append("<td>Button1</td>" +"<td>Button2</td>");
});
```

if you want to select only the `<tr>` inside body then use `tbody` before `tr` because `thead` also have `tr`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#table tbody tr").append("<td>Button1</td>" +"<td>Button2</td>");
    });
```

Comment: Looks like this now

https://gyazo.com/a6340b7262c8599e8539c4fd378f691f

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s6u3mnv1/

There you go, keep in mind it's a work in progress

Comment: @Robin Borg So that is problem with that. Its working fine

Comment: Right now the "buttons" are next to the tableheads, I want them to be next to each td row.

Comment: that makes sense! However, it doesn't seem to work for me right now. As you can see in my html code, I dont have tbody tag inside the table. I tried adding an empty <tbody></tbody> after the <thead> but nothing changes.

Comment: @Robin Borg Then you need to add the table rows which you will insert after to `tbody` not table. try that

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that when loading the tabledata from an url

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a function at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table tr").append("<td>Button1</td><td>Button2</td>");
});
```

Comment: I think `each()` is not necesarry. `$("#table tr").append(...)` will append it to all `tr`s

Comment: Oh yes @MaheerAli I forgot about that.

Comment: Yes @JoSSte - I was referring to a named function e.g. `function buttons() {...}`